# Why do I need at least 30 wins to earn the relative special weapon badge?

Tags: achievements, splatoon-3

According to [Splatoon wiki](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Badge):

> If a player wins a match with a special weapon a certain number of times, they obtain normal, silver and gold badges.

The number of required wins are 30, 180 and 1200.

This is not always true, because sometimes I need more than 30 wins to actually get the badge. Are there any missing requirements or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually **use** the special weapon in all 30 of those games, not just win them.

I won 30 turf wars without getting the badge, then checking my history I realized I didn't use the Jetpack in the last one, hence I didn't get the badge.

Winning another match successfully let me unlock the Jetpack badge for 30 wins.